# Does the compiler matter when compiling R packages from source?

Tags: r, compilation, rstudio

I use lots of R packages and update them regularly via RStudio with `update.packages()` and `BiocManager::install()` functions. Often they need compilation from source:

```
There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
          binary source needs_compilation
RSQLite    2.1.2  2.1.3              TRUE
rversions  2.0.0  2.0.1             FALSE
survival   3.1-7  3.1-8              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the packages which need compilation? (Yes/no/cancel)
```

I am wondering if it matters which compiler we choose, i.e. gcc, clang, clang4, etc.?:

```
$ cat ~/.R/Makevars 
#CFLAGS +=             -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu99
FLIBS=-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin19/9.2.0
MAKE=make -j8
CC=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang
CXX=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
CXX1X=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
CXX98=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
CXX11=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
CXX14=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
CXX17=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
```

If so, in which way do they matter i.e. speed, runtime, bugginess, efficiency, etc. for the R packages?

Comment: Yes, it matters. Your clang version is not likely to work with Catalina. I think it's up to clang8 now. Read the Installation notes for the MacOS branch of R.